# Automatic text expansion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In NetBeans, there's a handy feature that expands common Java directives. e.g.:

I type **psfi** and it expands to `private static final int`.

or **Psfs** become `public static final String`

Is there an equivalent feature in Eclipse? And how do I configure / enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Preferences / Java / Editor / Templates` to add your own template.

[image]

I just tested with your template, it works as expected.

Comment: Do I have to hit <CTRL>-SPACE after psf? or is there a way of making it expand automatically?

Comment: In Eclipse you expand using ctrl-space. Is that really a problem ?

Comment: It is just another keystroke, and then select from the dialog box; but it's reasonably close to what I want.

Comment: @Denys Séguret yes it is. It's actually a time killer while other IDEs can expand it instantly...

Answer (score 1):

There are some inbuilt short-forms also.
for eg. type syso and press Ctrl+space, it will complete it as system.out.println();
or type main and press CTRl+space, it will complete as public static void main()